# String length for various encoding

Tags: php

I'm doing application for string length check. When checking Cyrillic string there shows wrong because of the unicode. How to solve this problem?

```
$str=strlen ('abc');
echo $str;  // result is 3

$str=strlen ('АБС');
echo $str;  // result is 6. How to find correct value
```

Comment: You want ***m**ulti **b**yte* strlen() e.g. `mb_strlen()`

Comment: @Rizier123, [check this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d361b18ec5fc2c56fd6195854c66356cb438e406)

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Pass `UTF-8` as second parameter like in the dupe.

Comment: @Rizier123 thanks bro..

Answer (score 0):

Was little curious about this question.

First options is as suggested by `Rizier123`(no doubt, that works perfectly.)

Second:

You can also use `utf8_decode()` to get the result.

```
<?php
    $str=strlen (utf8_decode('АБС'));
    echo $str;
?>
```

Check [demo here](https://eval.in/481962)

Comment: utf8_decode is deprecated since PHP 8.2.0. See alternatives at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php